# A non-arbitrary quantum-classical cut?

Tags: quantum-mechanics, classical-mechanics

I do not believe that there is a so-called quantum-classical cut, a dividing line between the classical and quantum realm. In principle, everything would be quantum. However, IF one takes the cut seriously for some independent reason, what would be a non-arbitrary way to draw the line?

One thing that comes to my mind is to say the following:

**For any $x$, $x$ is a quantum object just in case the Compton wavelength of $x$ is shorter than the Plank length.**

The reasoning behind this is that
i) an object is properly quantum only if there is a Compton wavelength associated with it, and ii) any length smaller than the Plank length is physically meaningless.

Since the Compton wavelength of $x = h/mc$, where $m$ is the mass of the body, macroscopic objects will be classified as classical objects as they should be.

I am curious if there is any intrinsic problem with this suggestion. If not, I might reconsider my assumption that the quantum-classical cut is not real.

Comment: I guess it's also important to specify _which_ quantum effects stop working above $m \approx 1.37 \cdot 10^{-7}\,\text{kg}$. For example the [Harris group](https://doi.org/10.1103/PhysRevA.92.061801) managed to cool a vibrational mode of a mechanical oscillator with $m = 0.43 \cdot 10^{-7}\,\text{kg}$ to a mean phonon number $\bar{n} < 1$. So probably, this experiment will also work for larger masses. But it might be that creating a superposition of this mass in two different places wouldn't work because of gravitational decoherence.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are deep into quantum interpretation territory - namely what is "real" in the quantum world. Be prepared for arguments based on "intuition" (which reminds me of a [Monty Python sketch](https://www.cse.unsw.edu.au/%7Enorman/Jokes-file/LogicProfessor.html))

Generally QM is considered to apply to objects of all sizes, from elementary particles to Elephants to massive stars to Galaxies. The Plank length doesn't really come into it.

The Quantum-Classical cut only really make sense if you believe that QM is a theory about information, about what the observer knows, and that the waveform is not real (See Schrodinger's Cat). If you believe that the waveform is real, then it is difficult to see how to make sense of the cut between the quantum and classical.